# SQL join codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Codeigniter 4 is throwing the following error:

> Argument 2 passed to view() must be of the type array, null given
> called in D:\xampp\htdocs\lordeCI\app\Controllers\Blog.php on line 35

That is about the block of code below:

```
public function post($post_id)
    {
        $model = new BlogModel();
        $posts = $model->select('*')->select('c1.nome as categoria, c2.nome as categoria_2')
            ->join('categorias c1', 'c1.categoria_id = posts.categoria', 'inner')
            ->join('categorias c2', 'c2.categoria_id = posts.categoria_2', 'inner')
            ->find($post_id);

        return view('posts/single_post',$posts);
    }
```

I am very grateful to who help me with that.

Comment: You have to pass `array` instead of `variable`. Please replace `$posts` to `$data['posts']` and pass `$data` in view and in view print `$posts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can remove the first select *, you either select * or define the fields you want.

You should do that only if you need all the columns from table 1 and just some from table 2.

Like so:

```
$model->select('*, c1.nome as categoria, c2.nome as categoria_2');
```

Second you need to send an array so that those keys can be turned into variables. In this case if you want a variable called posts in your view your should send it an index in your array.

```
    public function post($post_id)
    {
        $model = new BlogModel();
        $data['posts'] = $model->select('c1.nome as categoria, c2.nome as categoria_2')
             ->join('categorias c1', 'c1.categoria_id = posts.categoria', 'inner')
             ->join('categorias c2', 'c2.categoria_id = posts.categoria_2', 'inner')
             ->find($post_id);

        return view('posts/single_post',$data);
    }
```

Comment: `select('*, c1.nome as categoria, c2.nome as categoria_2')`in case you need to access other columns too

Comment: feel free to edit my comment into your answer, comments can become obsolete